# Composite Primary key in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have this error showing on my page.

> Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not
>   supported. You should split the parameter into the explicit fields and
>   bind them separately.

Well in my database, I have three tables which are **Campagne**, **Contact** and **campagne_contact**. A contact can be in many campagne as possible but cannot be in the same campagne twice, this is why I have a composite primary key in **campagne_contact**.

I have used ManyToMany relationships successfully but this time, **campagne_contact** has an extra field which is **sms**.

And I don't understand what I have to do although what I have to do is in the error. Can  I have some explanation please?

```
     namespace Sfr\PowerSBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;

    /**
     * CampagneContact
     *
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="campagne_contact")
     */
    class CampagneContact
    {
        /**
         * @Id
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contact")
         */
        private $contact;

        /**
         * @Id
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Campagne")
         */
        private $campagne;   
    }

<?php

namespace Sfr\PowerSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Campagne
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="campagne")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sfr\PowerSBundle\Repository\CampagneRepository")
 */
class Campagne
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lundi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $lundi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mardi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mardi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mercredi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mercredi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="jeudi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $jeudi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vendredi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $vendredi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="samedi", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $samedi;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dimanche", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dimanche;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="time", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="time", nullable=false)
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="note", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isEnabled;

    private $nbContacts;
    public $nbJours = 0;

     /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection|Contact[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Contact", mappedBy="campagnes")
     */
    private $contacts;

<?php

namespace Sfr\PowerSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sfr\PowerSBundle\Repository\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cellphone", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cellphone;

    /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sfr\PowerSBundle\Entity\Client")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
   */
    private $client;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->campagnes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

By the way I am using Symfony 3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can a campaign have **many** contacts?

Comment: Yes a campaign can have many contacts

Comment: you should also provide in which repository method you get that error